# Calculating textbox.text with two selected combobox items

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, combobox

My problem: Id like to , after two   `combobox`     variables are selected, to divide these two and set the `Textbox` to the result of the calculation.

**The two `Comboboxes`: Körpergröße & Gewicht**

**The `textbox`: BMI**

First of all, the code im using ( which apparently isnt working now)

```
        protected void Körpergröße_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        //In this way you can compare the value and if it is possible to convert into an integer. 
        if (int.TryParse(Körpergröße.SelectedItem.ToString(), out a) && int.TryParse(Gewicht.SelectedItem.ToString(), out b))
        {

            fillTextBox(a, b);
        }
    }

    protected void Gewicht_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        if (int.TryParse(Körpergröße.SelectedItem.ToString(), out a) && int.TryParse(Gewicht.SelectedItem.ToString(), out b))
        {

            fillTextBox(a, b);
        }
    }

    private void fillTextBox(int value1, int value2)
    {
        BMI.Text = (value1 / value2).ToString();
    }
```

The default values of the two `comboboxes` are strings.. ("Bitte auswählen")

Pictures how it looks like now. After two int values are selected, the result of the calculation should appear in the `BMI Textbox`.

[image: Picture]

It would be nice if someone could answer me with a code with some sidenotes, in order for me to understand..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Integer values cannot be divided without remainder. So you need to change `int` type to `float` type:

```
private void Gewicht_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   float a;
   float b;
   if (float.TryParse(Körpergröße.SelectedItem.ToString(), out a) && float.TryParse
(Gewicht.SelectedItem.ToString(), out b))
   {
      fillTextBox(a, b);
      string str = "";
   }
}
```

If you divide two integers, for example:

```
int k=130/150;
```

In real life, we know that `k` will be `0.86`. But there is no chance to show remainder for type `integer` cause this type is indivisible. `int` type cannot have value as `0,5` or `8.8`. It can be just `1`, `5` or any integer type.

But `float` type can store(have) values such as `100,5` or `233.333`. And this is a reason why you see `0` instead of your value.

If you want to limit count of numbers after integer value, you can use overloading of `.ToString()` method:

```
private void fillTextBox(float value1, float value2)
{
    textBox.Text = ((value1 / value2)).ToString("0.00");            
}
```

See [Custom Numeric Format Strings on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) for more details

Comment: @Sasa feel free to ask any question!:)

Comment: @Sasa if my reply helps to solve your problem, you can assign it as an answer to simplify the future search of other people.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using the selectionChanged event and attaching that to your comboBoxes, getting the selected value from both, then ensuring you don't have any `null` values (`string` can be null, but `int` can't) so something more like this:

XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="cb1" SelectionChanged="GetText" SelectionMode="Single">
  <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox Name="cb2" SelectionChanged="GetText" SelectionMode="Single">
  <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

C#

```
void GetText(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    ComboBoxItem item1 = cb1.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem);
    ComboBoxItem item2 = cb2.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem);

    if(item1 == null || item2 == null)
       return;
    //convert to # with your tryParse
    fillTextBox(item1, item2);
}
```